# Bootstrap: centering the columns in fluid row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

#### (09/30/2015) Solution to this problem was added at the bottom

I've been searching and playing with CSS files but I can't seem to get this correctly, instead, I'm just patching up css with bad solutions.

#### Current setup

I have a row with `<div class="row-fluid">` and this row has 24 columns div `<div class="col-xs-1 skills-item">`. It looks fine to me when I'm on desktop, but when I'm in mobile device, they move around and setup with ugly centering position.

I wanted to use `row-fluid` option because I didn't want 24 columns stacking and taking so much space.

See the images below.

*Full screen*

[image: Full Screen]

*Smaller Screen*

[image: Smaller Screen]

*Even Smaller screen*

[image: Even Smaller Screen]

*Mobile*

[image: Mobile]

#### What I did

I added media queries to handle different screen sizes, but I'm sure this is a hard coded way and I should avoid as much as possible. Here's the snippet

```
@media(max-width:1000px) {
    #skills .skills-item {
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 1200px){
    #skills .skills-item {
        margin-right: 30px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
    #skills .skills-item {
        margin-right: 55px;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 466px) {
    #skills .skills-item {
        margin-right: 40px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 376px) {
    #skills .skills-item {
        margin-right: 40px;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
}
```

I mean this works, but still look ugly on some sizes.

#### Question

Is there any clean solution to make these columns center?

Something like `margin: 0 auto;` and centering all of the would be perfect, but it didn't work. (or maybe I just couldn't find where to place that)

The website I'm making is online for test purposes (not finished at all) [Here](http://saehunseanoh.me/#skills)

Thank you!

#### EDIT : added html and css

**HTML code** of this section. I'm pretty sure you don't need all 24 items but here.

```
    <!-- Skill Overview -->
    <section class="success" id="skills">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Skill Overview</h2>
                    <hr class="skills-hr">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-xs-1 skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">JAVA</span>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:150%;">JAVA</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">C</span>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:150%;">C</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">C++</span>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:150%;">C++</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">C#</span>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:150%;">C#</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link" style="padding-top:30px">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="color:#fff;">PYTHON</span>
                        <span class="skill-name">PYTHON</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link" style="padding-top:30px">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="color:#fff;">SPARC</span>
                        <span class="skill-name two-lines" style="font-size:90%">SPARC ASSEMBLY</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link" style="padding-top:30px">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:120%; color:#fff;">MIPS</span>
                        <span class="skill-name two-lines" style="font-size:90%">MIPS ASSEMBLY</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-1 skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-android fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line">ANDROID</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-html5 fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">HTML5</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-css3 fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">CSS3</span>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">JS</span>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:90%">JAVASCRIPT</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="php" class="skill-icon" src="images/php-logo.png" style="width:80%; margin-top:-10px">
                        <span class="skill-name">PHP SCRIPT</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="apache" class="skill-icon" src="images/apache-logo.png" style="width:75%;">
                        <span class="skill-name">APACHE SERVER</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-database fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:90%">SQL DATABASE</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="aws" class="skill-icon" src="images/aws-logo.png" style="width:50%;">
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:85%">Amazon Web Services</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-linux fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">LINUX</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-apple fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">OSX</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-windows fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:90%;">WINDOWS</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-git fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:75%">VERSION CONTROL <br>(GIT, SVN)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="eclipse" class="skill-icon" src="images/eclipse-logo.png" style="width:40%;">
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line">ECLIPSE</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="unity3d" class="skill-icon" src="images/unity3d-logo.png" style="width:40%;">
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line">UNITY3D</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="gdb" class="skill-icon" src="images/gdb-logo.png" style="width:70%; margin-top:-15px">
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">GDB</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-stack-exchange fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name two-lines" style="font-size:90%;">STACK EXCHANGE</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-pulse-grow skills-link skill-love">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-heart fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="color: #000; font-size: 120%"><b>LOVE</b></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /Skill Overview -->
```

**CSS part**

```
/* Skill Settings */
.skill-name {
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}


.skills-link:hover .skill-name {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.skills-link:hover .two-lines {
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.skills-link:hover .icon-one-line {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.skills-link:hover .skill-icon{
    display: none;
}

#skills .skills-item {
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 15px;
}


#skills .skills-item .skills-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #0F1A23;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

#skills .skills-link:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1.25s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1.25s;
    transition: all ease 1.25s;
}

#skills .skill-love:hover {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1.25s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1.25s;
    transition: all ease 1.25s;
}

#skills * {
    z-index: 2;
}

@media(max-width:1000px) {
    #skills .skills-item {
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 1200px){
    #skills .skills-item {
        margin-right: 30px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
    #skills .skills-item {
        margin-right: 55px;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 466px) {
    #skills .skills-item {
        margin-right: 40px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 376px) {
    #skills .skills-item {
        margin-right: 40px;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
}

/* End Skill Settings */
```

## Solution

**index.html**

```
    <!-- Skill Overview -->
    <section class="success" id="skills">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Skill Overview</h2>
                    <hr class="skills-hr">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- notice that I changed it from row-fluid to row-->
            <!-- also I changed each columns from col-xs-1 to col-sm-1 -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1 skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">JAVA</span>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:150%;">JAVA</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">C</span>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:150%;">C</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">C++</span>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:150%;">C++</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">C#</span>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:150%;">C#</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link" style="padding-top:30px">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="color:#fff;">PYTHON</span>
                        <span class="skill-name">PYTHON</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link" style="padding-top:30px">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="color:#fff;">SPARC</span>
                        <span class="skill-name two-lines" style="font-size:90%">SPARC ASSEMBLY</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link" style="padding-top:30px">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:120%; color:#fff;">MIPS</span>
                        <span class="skill-name two-lines" style="font-size:90%">MIPS ASSEMBLY</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-android fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line">ANDROID</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-html5 fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">HTML5</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-css3 fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">CSS3</span>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">JS</span>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:90%">JAVASCRIPT</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="php" class="skill-icon" src="images/php-logo.png" style="width:80%; margin-top:-10px">
                        <span class="skill-name">PHP SCRIPT</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="apache" class="skill-icon" src="images/apache-logo.png" style="width:75%;">
                        <span class="skill-name">APACHE SERVER</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-database fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:90%">SQL DATABASE</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="aws" class="skill-icon" src="images/aws-logo.png" style="width:50%;">
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:85%">Amazon Web Services</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-linux fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">LINUX</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-apple fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">OSX</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-windows fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:90%;">WINDOWS</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-git fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:75%">VERSION CONTROL <br>(GIT, SVN)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="eclipse" class="skill-icon" src="images/eclipse-logo.png" style="width:40%;">
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line">ECLIPSE</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="unity3d" class="skill-icon" src="images/unity3d-logo.png" style="width:40%;">
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line">UNITY3D</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="gdb" class="skill-icon" src="images/gdb-logo.png" style="width:70%; margin-top:-15px">
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">GDB</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-stack-exchange fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name two-lines" style="font-size:90%;">STACK EXCHANGE</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-pulse-grow skills-link skill-love">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-heart fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="color: #000; font-size: 120%"><b>LOVE</b></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /Skill Overview -->
```

**stylesheet.css**

```
/* Skill Settings */
.skill-name {
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

.skills-link:hover .skill-name {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.skills-link:hover .two-lines {
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.skills-link:hover .icon-one-line {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.skills-link:hover .skill-icon {
    display: none;
}

#skills {
    text-align: center;
}

#skills .skills-item {
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 95px;
    height:95px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#skills .skills-item .skills-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #0F1A23;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#skills .skills-link:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1.25s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1.25s;
    transition: all ease 1.25s;
}

#skills .skill-love:hover {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1.25s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1.25s;
    transition: all ease 1.25s;
}

#skills * {
    z-index: 2;
}

.col-sm-1 {
    padding: 0;
}
/* End Skill Settings */
```

**Screenshots**

[image: desktop]

[image: tablets]

[image: phones]

Comment: Can you post up the HTML and CSS so I can make a fiddle and show you a solution? You can do what you're wanting with display: inline-block.

Comment: Just added the code. It made the whole thread super long. Should I move it over to somewhere else ??

Comment: That should be fine since theyre in code blocks, give me one sec and ill submit and answer for you.

Comment: @Psyco430404 Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution modified from your code.

The CSS

```
/* Skill Settings */
.skill-name {
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}


.skills-link:hover .skill-name {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.skills-link:hover .two-lines {
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.skills-link:hover .icon-one-line {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.skills-link:hover .skill-icon{
    display: none;
}
#skills{
    text-align: center;
}
#skills .skills-item {
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#skills .skills-item .skills-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #0F1A23;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#skills .skills-link:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1.25s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1.25s;
    transition: all ease 1.25s;
}

#skills .skill-love:hover {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1.25s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1.25s;
    transition: all ease 1.25s;
}

#skills * {
    z-index: 2;
}

/* End Skill Settings */
```

The HTML

```
<!-- Skill Overview -->
    <section class="success" id="skills">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Skill Overview</h2>
                    <hr class="skills-hr">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-xs-1 skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">JAVA</span>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:150%;">JAVA</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">C</span>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:150%;">C</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">C++</span>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:150%;">C++</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">C#</span>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:150%;">C#</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link" style="padding-top:30px">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="color:#fff;">PYTHON</span>
                        <span class="skill-name">PYTHON</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link" style="padding-top:30px">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="color:#fff;">SPARC</span>
                        <span class="skill-name two-lines" style="font-size:90%">SPARC ASSEMBLY</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link" style="padding-top:30px">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:120%; color:#fff;">MIPS</span>
                        <span class="skill-name two-lines" style="font-size:90%">MIPS ASSEMBLY</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-1 skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-android fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line">ANDROID</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-html5 fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">HTML5</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-css3 fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">CSS3</span>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <span class="skill-icon" style="font-size:150%; color:#fff;">JS</span>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:90%">JAVASCRIPT</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="php" class="skill-icon" src="images/php-logo.png" style="width:80%; margin-top:-10px">
                        <span class="skill-name">PHP SCRIPT</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="apache" class="skill-icon" src="images/apache-logo.png" style="width:75%;">
                        <span class="skill-name">APACHE SERVER</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-database fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:90%">SQL DATABASE</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="aws" class="skill-icon" src="images/aws-logo.png" style="width:50%;">
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:85%">Amazon Web Services</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-linux fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">LINUX</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-apple fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">OSX</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-windows fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:90%;">WINDOWS</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-git fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name" style="font-size:75%">VERSION CONTROL <br>(GIT, SVN)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="eclipse" class="skill-icon" src="images/eclipse-logo.png" style="width:40%;">
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line">ECLIPSE</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="unity3d" class="skill-icon" src="images/unity3d-logo.png" style="width:40%;">
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line">UNITY3D</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <img alt="gdb" class="skill-icon" src="images/gdb-logo.png" style="width:70%; margin-top:-15px">
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="font-size:120%;">GDB</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-float-shadow skills-link">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-stack-exchange fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name two-lines" style="font-size:90%;">STACK EXCHANGE</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1  skills-item">
                    <div class="hvr-pulse-grow skills-link skill-love">
                        <i class="skill-icon fa fa-heart fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="skill-name icon-one-line" style="color: #000; font-size: 120%"><b>LOVE</b></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /Skill Overview -->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/or10qmkk/

You had a few issues with the way things were setup, your links for instance had mad bleed off with the padding because you never setup border-box so your heights were varied. From there I set up the .skills-item to be inline block and I set the #skills div to text-align center to center them.

Let me know in the comments if you have questions.

Comment: This works very well with the `centering` part, but it cuts off my boxes like [this](http://i.imgur.com/EcKvwNd.png) because of the positioning I think? Please take a look at [this](http://i.imgur.com/3nTu5Ix.png) and [this](http://i.imgur.com/bScYSkS.png). By looking at the tags, I'm assuming it's the `padding-left:15px` from `col-*` in `bootstrap.css` .. what should I do ? Should I override it?

Comment: If you look in the css, I set up a hard width, if you remove that it should allow everything to fit normally, you could also just adjust the width to the right amount and it should work.

Comment: I fixed it by changing all `col-xs-1` to `col-sm-1` apparently `col-xs-1` has better collapsing feature but worse centering? Also I gave 95px margins to the `.skill-item` for spacing. I added `.col-sm-1 { padding:0 }` to override bootstrap default padding (15px left,right). Thank you!

Comment: No problem dude, wanna link me to the final thing so I can see everything in action?

Comment: It's updated in the website here: http://saehunseanoh.me/#skills . I'll update this thread with the solution as well!

Answer (score 1):

None of your `div` boxes are actually in their row container.

In other words, each `<div class="col-xs-1 skills-item">` is outside `<div class="row-fluid">`, which is a collapsed box since each div is absolutely position by the `hvr-float-shadow` class.

If you put a border around `.row-fluid` you'll notice it's just a flat line above the boxes.

[image]

There are several ways to "clearfix" the problem. You can try adding `overflow: hidden` to the container class (`.row-fluid`), as one method. The row now expands to wrap all the boxes.

Then to keep the boxes centered I would suggest making each box `inline-block`.

`.col-xs-1 skills-item { display: inline-block; }`

and applying `text-align: center;` to the parent container:

`.row-fluid { text-align: center; }`

This should keep the boxes centered in all screen sizes. Just make sure to remove all the margin patches you had added.

Comment: Sorry, but am I missing something? I just added `border: solid 2px #fff;` in `.row-fluid`, it draw a white border just find and my skill boxes are in the border... :o

Comment: I'm on your site. Dev tools is saying otherwise. Will update my answer with a screen shot.

Comment: Hmm this is the screenshot after adding the border. [http://i.imgur.com/6mTpfuH.png](http://i.imgur.com/6mTpfuH.png)

Comment: Yup. That's the way it *should* work. But again, I'm just working off of the link you provided in your question. Maybe it's outdated?

Comment: Putting that aside (since it's working for you anyway), what about the centering part. Did the `text-align: center` work for you?

Comment: No it didn't.. it's very strange because my github has the most up to date code (exact same copy of my local one). I'm working on the other solution right now. I'll update you. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that it happens when I add more then 12 columns in one row. Bootstrap will automatically format it correctly but only inspect element would show it as `div class="row"` is messed up. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you got the issue resolved.